# After Insert and Update Triggers - Good Practices

Tags: sql, database, triggers, database-administration

It is a good practice to have a separate trigger for After Insert and another one for After Update or there is no problem in having both in the same logic?

Also from a perspective of performance it will be better to have them isolated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they do exactly the same thing, then make it one trigger, it will be easier to maintain. If they do slightly different things, it might be faster to do separte triggers but slightly harder to maintain, so I would go for one unless there is a performance problem. If they do something very different, go fo two triggers.

Comment: Thank you, I share the same opinion.